# incorrect recordio format using Augmented manifest file from sagemaker ground truth

Tags: python, object-detection, amazon-sagemaker

I have used Sagemaker Ground truth to create annotation file.

Following below 2 links, I am trying to create a training job, then perform hyper parameter tuning.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/augmented-manifest.html
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/ground_truth_labeling_jobs/object_detection_augmented_manifest_training/object_detection_augmented_manifest_training.ipynb
However, I keep having below error

**ClientError: Unable to parse record. Please make sure input data is in correct recordio format. , exit code: 2**

This is the code

```
#model config 
od_model = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(training_image,
                                         role,
                                         instance_count=1,
                                         instance_type='ml.p3.2xlarge',
                                         train_volume_size=50,
                                         train_max_run=360000,
                                         input_mode='Pipe',
                                         output_path=s3_output_location,
                                         sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)

# Set hyperparameters
od_model.set_hyperparameters(base_network='resnet-50',
                             use_pretrained_model=1,
                             num_classes=2,
                             mini_batch_size=5,
                             epochs=30,
                             learning_rate=0.001,
                             lr_scheduler_step='10,20',
                             lr_scheduler_factor=0.1,
                             optimizer='adam',
                             num_training_samples=str(num_training_samples))


#data
train_data = "s3://bucket/.../manifests/output/output.manifest"
validation_data = "s3://bucket/.../manifests/output/.manifest"

train_channel = sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput(train_data, distribution='FullyReplicated', content_type='application/x-recordio', 
                                               s3_data_type='AugmentedManifestFile',
                                               attribute_names=attribute_names,
                                                input_mode='Pipe',
                                                #record_wrapping='RecordIO')
#did same for validation
```

What is wrong with the code or my annotation file?

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of issues with the snippet as it is now but I think your code looks generally correct. I can make some suggestions that are a bit too long for a comment, but not sure whether they'd solve it:

First, it looks like you're trying to comment out the `record_wrapping` parameter. Did you try it both with and without? [RecordWrapperType](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_Channel.html#sagemaker-Type-Channel-RecordWrapperType) tells SageMaker to wrap individual records from (raw JSON-Lines) input data into proper RecordIO format - so I would expect you **will need** `record_wrapping="RecordIO"` to avoid 'Unable to parse record' when using augmented manifest files in this mode.

Second, it's not quite clear what your `attribute_names` are set as. Assuming you're using the built-in object detection algorithm, you'll want exactly 2 in the correct order 1) the image `source-ref` and 2) the annotation attribute. Under the hood (as mentioned in the [Augmented Manifest File doc you linked](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/augmented-manifest.html#augmented-manifest-stream), SageMaker is converting each manifest records `{"prop1": "...", "prop2": "...", ...}` to multiple RecordIO records containing either actual S3 object data (for `-ref` field names) or the original manifest data (for field names not ending `-ref`). Therefore you need to set `attribute_names` to exclude the `-metadata` attribute added by Ground Truth, and ensure the algorithm receives a stream of [image], [annotation], [image], [annotation], ... as it expects.

Third, you could maybe double-check your manifest files for any malformed rows or re-try with a smaller extract that you're confident has only valid rows: For example if either of your expected attribute names are missing, or blank, or the S3 object might not exist or etc. It looks like you might have a typo on your validation S3URI `output/.manifest`.

Here's [another example notebook using pipe mode / augmented manifests for object detection](https://github.com/apac-ml-tfc/computer-vision-workshops/tree/master/gt_object_det) that I've used successfully in the past, but it's pretty old now so might have collected some bugs. The code looks pretty much the same as the two you shared already.

In the unlikely event that you're trying to build your own algorithm using augmented manifests + pipe mode, it's worth mentioning the [MXNet implementation](https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.7/api/python/docs/api/mxnet/recordio/index.html#mxnet.recordio.MXRecordIO) (based on [DMLC core](https://github.com/dmlc/dmlc-core/blob/main/src/recordio.cc)) SageMaker built-ins seem to use is a bit more complex than what you might think if you read the [Apache Mesos definition of RecordIO standard](https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/recordio/)... It's not just a case of prepending the record size and newline to the record data - there's additional alignment going on.

Comment: Thanks! I referred to your notebook for channel setting and it worked for me.

Comment: I also would like to check, I saw in your git you tried both 1. custom label in Rekognition and 2. Sagemaker MXnet (and a few other custom models in Sagemaker). 
Do you find  any performance (metrics) difference? I am trying both Rekognition and Sagemkaer MXnet, somehow even after tuning Rekognition works much better than MXnet

Comment: Yeah I believe Rekognition will usually be more accurate as it's doing more advanced things e.g. ensembling techniques, proprietary base models, etc. One trade-off is inference [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/pricing/) will probably be more than a single model deployed on SageMaker. You could also check out [SageMaker JumpStart](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/doc_utils/pretrainedmodels.html) to find a selection of other pre-built algos for object detection... (Or even bring a custom one from open source or etc)